# Since linking process only involve Section Header, can I remove Program Header from shared object?

Tags: linux, elf, dynamic-linking

As I read from many blogs. ELF format's linking process only involve Section Header Table. And Shared Object file is used for dynamic linking. Does that means I can remove the Program Header Table from all Shared Object file ?

Answer (score 0):

> As I read from many blogs. ELF format's linking process only involve Section Header Table.

There are *two* kinds of linking -- static and dynamic.

- Static linking only involves sections, and *builds* the program header table.
- Dynamic linking only involves program header table.

> Does that means I can remove the Program Header Table from all Shared Object file ?

No. No tools exist to do this, and if you succeed the resulting shared library will be *useless* for dynamic linking.

You can however remove *sections* from the shared library -- they aren't used for anything other than as a debugging help.

Comment: There's some fundamental concept I don't quite understand about ELF file. Can a small piece of content inside ELF file not belong to any section